# JVM error on starting Wowza Media server

Tags: linux, jvm, wowza

I have installed Wowza Media Server 3.5 on a CentOS based VPS. During starting Wowza media server for first time i got the error.

- Error occurred during initialization of VM
- Could not reserve enough space for object heap
- Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
- Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Which i suppose is due to memory allocation for JVM

The output of *ulimit -a*

- core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
- data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
- scheduling priority             (-e) 0
- file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
- pending signals                 (-i) 794624
- max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
- max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
- open files                      (-n) 1024
- pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
- POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
- real-time priority              (-r) 0
- stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
- cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
- max user processes              (-u) 1024
- virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
- file locks                      (-x) unlimited

And of

*free -m*

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:          1024       1024          0          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:       1024          0
Swap:            0          0          0

There is also an alias entry like

*alias java='java -Xms8m -Xmx64m'*

Which could also be the reason for JVM error.